# Centering an element inside div, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I'm using bootstrap. The idea is to center the `h1` element inside the `div`, but I haven't as of now. It's always aligned to the left. I tried using the bootstrap's `center-block` helper class, and the `float: none, margin: 0 auto` approach, but it doesn't work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            ...
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="some-div" class="row">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Like, is there a bootstrap specific way (e.g., some other helper class) of doing this? Or is it simply not possible?

Comment: I don't see an H1 here. Have you tried [text-center](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)?

Comment: sorry, yeah, the p should be an h1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a nested row, and Bootstrap provides **[text alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)** for you. A heading is a block-level element, but you can apply the text class to it or a parent element.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="some-div">
        <h1 class="text-center">An H1 Heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3gmptgnf/)

Comment: isherwood, you're right, the nested row wasn't necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Text H1</h1>
</div>
```